# PowerCenter - XML Target - Create more of an XML

Tags: xml, etl, informatica-powercenter

It creates more of an XML file and I want everything in one file.
where is the problem?

Mapping

[image]

XML TARGET

[image]

OUTPUT

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are repeating the PK for PurchaseOrder. Pass the PK through a aggregator (group by on that port) and then connect it to the PK in target.

Comment: add the transformation but not working. i tried for other examples. Thaks +1